# long polling using php mysql

Tags: mysql, long-integer, polling

I found a script that uses php long polling. It uses the following code to see if the text file is changed and returns the content. This is received by the browser.
How can i change this to read a table and see if there are new events ?

```js
$filename= dirname(__FILE__)."/data.txt";

$lastmodif = isset( $_GET['timestamp'])? $_GET['timestamp']: 0 ;
$currentmodif=filemtime($filename);


while ($currentmodif <= $lastmodif) {
usleep(10000);
clearstatcache();
$currentmodif =filemtime($filename);
} 

$response = array();
$response['msg'] =Date("h:i:s")." ".file_get_contents($filename);
$response['timestamp']= $currentmodif;
echo json_encode($response);
```

How can i know if theres a new post ?

Comment: Please, don't use that. It makes no sense. You, who are the developer of your site, should have the means to trigger a notification when an insert happens using the **code you made**. If you can't figure out a way to do that, just don't use random scripts. This script is bad because: it doesn't use OS event system to get notified about changes. It polls every millisecond - that will hammer your CPU because sleep literally wastes cpu cycles. It also operates on file system, causing additional overhead due to how FS work. If you decide to use it, good luck.

Comment: but it is Long polling script, it is not hammer CPU

Comment: Why would you verify what I wrote about `usleep` and OS event interface not being used, right? If "*it is not hammer CPU*" then ok, good luck.

Comment: Please tell me the safest method of notification

Comment: I'd suggest that you ask about your real problem and not this attempted solution. There's a reason why you want to poll for new posts, so ask about that instead of this script. How's that sound? What you're having here is known as [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I need a new massage notification script with php, ajax, mysql